# Error:(203, 52) error: cannot access zza class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

In my `Gradle` file. All services are `google play service` and their version numbers are same but still having the same error. Where others suggested to use the same version of `firebase` and `google play service`. But I am not using firebase service.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
compile project(':library')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.1'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2'
```

}

Comment: Have you tried disabling proguard?

Comment: No, i haven't Let me try. I will get back to you.

Comment: Did but not working @ThomasEdwin